# Asp.net core 2.0 localization not working in partial view.

Tags: asp.net-core

I am implementing convention-based localization with embedded resource file.Here is my sample code.

**Parent View(Details.cshtml)**

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization
@model SampleLocalization.Models.BoatDetailsViewModel
@inject IViewLocalizer Localizer

<section class="location-map">
    <h4 class="section-title">
        @Localizer["Location"]
    </h4>
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="Latitude" />
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="Longitude" />
    <section id="map_canvas" style="min-height:525px;"></section>
</section>
@{
    await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_SendMessagePartial", 
    Model.SendMessageViewModel);
}
```

**Partial view(_SendMessagePartial.cshtml)**

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization 
@model SampleLocalization.Models.BoatSendMessageViewModel 
@inject IViewLocalizer Localizer 

<h5 >@Localizer["Send Message"]</h5>
```

### @Localizer["Send Message"] is not properly translated

**Resource file structure as like below**

- Solution

  - Resources

    - Views

      - Boat

        - Details.de-DE.resx

*Note: Resource folder structure is as same as view folder structure*

Comment: Do you have an example of what you're using in your Startup.cs?

Comment: Any updates in this topic? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: Basically, I was new and I thought Resource file for main view would work for that view as well as all the partial views, but it wasn't. later on, I found following solutions. 

Corresponding Resource files must be there for main views as well as partial views. For example. 

Details.cshtml  => Details.de-DE.resx 

_SendMessagePartial.cshtml => _SendMessagePartial.de-DE.resx 

Pass injected Localizer variable to partial view from main view with ViewDateDictionary, and use that variable in partial view.

Answer (score 5):

Basically, the problem is because it is a different file, so translation should be in `Solution/Resources/Views/Boat/_SendMessagePartial.de-DE.resx`. The workaround is to create shared resoource file. You can add empty `SharedResource` class into the root of the project and then use `IStringLocalizer<SharedResource>` instead of `IViewLocalizer` in your view.

Here are docs related to that https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-2.2